# syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/ ")

Tags: bash

I have the following bash script

```
# 1 + x^2/2! + x^4/4! + ... + x^(2n)/(2*n)!
#!/bin/bash
factorial() {
    n=$1
    fact=1
    for ((i = 2; i <= $n; i++)); do
        fact=$(expr $fact \* $i)
    done
    return $fact
}

read -p "x = " x
read -p "n = " n

sum=0
for ((i = 1; i <= n; i++)); do
    val=$((2 ** ($i - 1)))
    ex=$(($x ** $val))
    f=$(factorial $val)
    a=$(($ex / $f))
    sum=$(($sum + $a))
done
echo $sum
```

I am trying to achieve the above series. I don't need a solution. I just couldn't figure out why the error is coming.

Error:

```
x = 1
n = 2
sum_of_series.sh: line 20: 1 / : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/ ")
```

Comment: (a) The shebang is not being processed. It has to be the first line in the script -- no preceding comments.

Comment: (b) The return from a function is a status -- probably limited to 0..255. Not suitable for arithmetic values. In any case, the `$( )` syntax collects stdout, not the return status. `$f` is empty. The function must echo or printf the value to get it into `f`.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant since this is basically the answer (`f` being empty, making `a=$(($ex / $f))` evaluate to the syntactically invalid `a=$((1 / ))`), you might as well post it as such ...

Comment: @Paul_Pedant thanks it worked. Also, the additional explanation was great too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is caused by the line `a=$(($ex / $f))`, because there is no operand following the `/` (divide) operator. So the immediate suspicion is that the variable `f` is an empty string.

The cause of that is the behaviour of the `$( )` command substitution when `f` is assigned. This collects the contents of stdout when the enclosed command pipeline is executed. As your `factorial()` function writes nothing to stdout, the value assigned to f is empty. The solution is to echo or print the value, in place of the `return` -- e.g. as `printf '%s\n' "${fact}"`.

Some additional notes that might be helpful:

The value in the return statement represents the status of the function, not any data it may have produced. In the absence of a return statement, the exit status of the last command executed in the function is passed back to the caller.

The return status is truncated to 8 bits, and is unsigned, so it can only take the range 0-255.

In addition, the status of external commands has further conventions. Processes terminated by a signal get a status of 128 + the signal number. If the shell fails to create a new process, or to execute the command, 126 or 127 may be returned. Status 0 is conventionally success, and any small integer from 1 up indicates a command-detected error or unusual result. I would consider it wise to follow the same conventions in my shell functions, and never to return a data value this way.

Shell arithmetic is (according to the GNU/bash manual) evaluated in fixed-width integers. On my system, that appears to be 64-bit signed integers, but it may vary across systems and distros. 31 bits is only sufficient to hold 12!, and 63 bits only holds 20!, which may limit your scope.

This fragment shows Bash arithmetic overflowing 63 bits, somewhere around 9.22e+18.

```
Paul--) for k in {1..10}; do
> printf '%s %s\n' $k $(( 3000000000000000000 * k ))
> done
1 3000000000000000000
2 6000000000000000000
3 9000000000000000000
4 -6446744073709551616
5 -3446744073709551616
6 -446744073709551616
7 2553255926290448384
8 5553255926290448384
9 8553255926290448384
10 -6893488147419103232
Paul--)
```

My go-to for large numbers is the dc command, which does unconstrained numeric size, but requires RPN (reverse polish notation). This fragment generates the RPN commands to list factorials up to 10!

```
Paul--) { echo 1; seq -s ' p * p ' 2 10; echo ' p * p q'; }
1
2 p * p 3 p * p 4 p * p 5 p * p 6 p * p 7 p * p 8 p * p 9 p * p 10
 p * p q
Paul--)
```

and this is the execution (but I tested up to 400!):

```
Paul--) { echo 1; seq -s ' p * p ' 2 10; echo ' p * p q'; } | dc
2
2
3
6
4
24
5
120
6
720
7
5040
8
40320
9
362880
10
3628800
Paul--)
```